# NoClassDefFoundError on creating IgniteSinkConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite

I am trying to get a distributed setup for the ignite-connector to run. Sadly, it does not work. I was able to grab the log on creation of the connector via the api.

### API POST payload to `/connectors`

```json
{
    "name": "ignite-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "2",
        "topics": "someTopic1",
        "cacheName": "myCache",
        "cacheAllowOverwrite": true,
        "igniteCfg":"/opt/ignite/examples/config/example-cache.xml"}
    }
}
```

I set up the ignite-connector as a plugin. I built an uber-jar from [the repo](https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions/tree/master/modules/kafka-ext) and put it to a separate direcotry and included it as plugin in the `.properties` file I am using to start `connect-distributed.sh`.

I set the classpath for the jobs for both the connetor and kafka I am managing with systemd:

```
Environment=CLASSPATH=/opt/kafka/ignite-connector/*
```

Following the full error log:

```
[2022-11-17 19:49:30,268] INFO [ignite-connector|worker] SinkConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkConnector
        errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = ignite-connector
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 2
        topics = [someTopic1]
        topics.regex =
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SinkConnectorConfig:376)
[2022-11-17 19:49:30,272] INFO [ignite-connector|worker] EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkConnector
        errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = ignite-connector
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 2
        topics = [someTopic1]
        topics.regex =
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig:376)
[2022-11-17 19:49:30,276] INFO [ignite-connector|worker] Instantiated connector ignite-connector with version 3.3.1 of type class org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:322)
[2022-11-17 19:49:30,276] INFO [ignite-connector|worker] Finished creating connector ignite-connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:347)
[2022-11-17 19:49:30,277] ERROR [ignite-connector|worker] WorkerConnector{id=ignite-connector} Error while starting connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:201)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ignite/internal/util/typedef/internal/A
        at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkConnector.start(IgniteSinkConnector.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:193)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:218)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:363)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:346)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:146)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:123)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2022-11-17 19:49:30,277] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1687)
[2022-11-17 19:49:30,280] ERROR [ignite-connector|worker] [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Failed to start connector 'ignite-connector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1811)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to start connector: ignite-connector
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$startConnector$35(DistributedHerder.java:1782)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:349)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:146)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:123)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to transition connector ignite-connector to state STARTED
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ignite/internal/util/typedef/internal/A
        at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkConnector.start(IgniteSinkConnector.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:193)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:218)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:363)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:346)
        ... 7 more
```

The mentioned class ([`A`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.ignite/ignite-core/2.14.0/org/apache/ignite/internal/util/typedef/internal/A.html)) is included in the ignite-core-2.9.1.jar that is bundeld in the uberJar in the Plugin directory.

Any pointers are appreciated

Comment: How did you install the connector? Do all ignite JAR files have the same permissions? Can you show `ls -laR <plugin.path>`?

Comment: @inetphantom, as I know, the `ignite-kafka-ext` module was excluded from the Ignite binary distribution beginning with version 2.10.0. Did you build it by yourself using the source code from the [ignite-extensions repository](https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions/tree/master/modules/kafka-ext)?

Comment: I think you should build the sources, as mentioned. Then you can choose to package an uber jar with all dependencies included. More specifically, your versions are wrong. You must use ignite-core 2.9.1, as listed in the version column https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-kafka/2.9.1 ; you might get a similar error, but the percentage of error is higher when you mix the versions around since they wouldn't be compiled together

Comment: In any case, you could try setting the `CLASSPATH`  environment variable to include `/plugin_path/*.jar` and restart connect worker

Comment: The plugin path config only scans for connector classes, connect transforms, converters, etc, not all classes from jars in the folder. For that, you do need to edit the CLASSPATH

Comment: @OneCricketeer I rechecked my built uberJar, added the old jars and it seems to work now - with the classpath hack. I don't see why, as the [official doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_running) and also [confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/5.1.2/connect/userguide.html#installing-plugins) tell you should not do it like that but as plugin.  Thanks for your help, please add your comments as answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding what "plugins" are. Those only are classes defined as implementations of Converters, Transforms, and Connectors.

Internal Ignite classes are none of these, so they wouldn't be loaded into the `plugin.path` classloader.

To fix this, you'll need to ensure you `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/ignite-files/*.jar` and you can use `jar -tf` commands to validate the class exists in any specific JAR  before running Connect process.

It is not a hack; that's just how Java Classloader works.